# How to patch Magento 2 Information Leakage scan result?

Tags: magento2.2, patches

I scanned the Magento 2 site from the official magento scanner and here's the result.

[image]

Any ideas on how and what specific patch to apply for this one?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your Magento version

Comment: @MazeStricks: Able to install the1378 path and other issues related to patch in magento scan report?

Answer (score 0):

If you go here https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-2.0.16-and-2.1.9-security-update it instructs you on what to do. It looks like this link is in the report. Are the instructions not correct?

Comment: Yeah, I already did look into that link. But I can't find where exactly the right file patch to download. Or does it suggest to upgrade the My current Magento 2 installation to the one described on that link. Just correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: Yep 2.0.x upgrade to 2.0.16 or if 2.1.x upgrade to 2.1.9. What version are you running? Do you know?

Answer (score 0):

No separate patches has been released for this issue. You have to upgrade your Magento version to either 2.0.16 or 2.1.9 accordingly. Please find the available security patches for Magento 2 in this link https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/. You will find an section **Magento Open Source Patches - 2.x** where the available patches are there.

So please upgrade your Magento version to either the latest release version or 2.0.16 or 2.1.9 to get this issue fixed.

Comment: Hello Raj, Thanks for the effort. But the Magento 2 version that the site is running is Magento 2.2, please advise thanks.

Comment: So you are in Magento 2.2.0 right

Comment: Yes! the store is running under that version Magento 2.2.0

Comment: As you are in Magento 2.2.0 you should not be getting API ACL and Information Leakage issues. These are than patches you are version might be missing and do apply these patches PRODSECBUG-2432, PRODSECBUG-2198 and try yet again

Comment: Hello Yes, I'm very sure that it is running under Magento 2.2.0 and it's pretty weird because of the staging website does not show that Information Leakage scan results while it is present on the live website. Anyway thanks for your comments.